# Example of volume form

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I know that a smooth $n$-manifold $M$ is orientable if and only if $M$ has a nowhere vanishing volume form. Since $S^n$ is a smooth orientable $n$-manifold, it has a nowhere vanshing volume form. Is there any simple example of that? i.e. nowhere vanishing smooth $n$-form on $S^n$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can take the interior product of the "outward normal" $\nu=\sum_{i=1}^nx^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ with the usual volume form $\mu=dx^1\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^n$ on $\Bbb{R}^n$, to get
\begin{align}
\sigma_{n-1}=\iota_{\nu}(\mu)=\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i-1}x^idx^1\wedge \cdots \widehat{dx^i}\wedge \cdots dx^n.
\end{align}
This (pulled back to $S^{n-1}$) will be a volume form for the sphere $S^{n-1}$. For example,
\begin{align}
\sigma_1&= x\,dy-y\,dx \tag{for $S^1$}\\
\sigma_2&=x\,dy\wedge dz - y\,dx\wedge dz +z\,dx\wedge dy\tag{for $S^2$}
\end{align}
and so on. I leave it to you to think about why it is nowhere-vanishing.

Comment: @barista yes, because if you evaluate the form $\sigma=\iota_{\nu}(\mu)$ at a point $p\in S^{n-1}$, and then apply that to an orthonormal basis $\{\xi_1,\dots, \xi_{n-1}\}$of $T_p(S^{n-1})$, then we get $\mu_p(\nu(p), \xi_1,\dots, \xi_{n-1})$. But now $\nu(p),\xi_1,\cdots, \xi_{n-1}$ is an orthogonal basis for $T_p(\Bbb{R}^n)$, and if you normalize $\nu(p)$, then it becomes an orthonormal basis. Now $\mu$ is the volume form of $\Bbb{R}^n$, so what is its value on an orthonormal basis?